# How do I host JSON files on my website?

Tags: json, host

One of my iPhone apps uses JSON data to populate it's database. However, I'd like to make that process automatic by hosting the JSON file online. How do I do this?

example of the content I want to host:

```
[{"Name":"John","Value":22,"Colour":"brown","City":"Auckland"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you just need a hosting, upload your file and point your app to that file thats it. Search for any free hosting on google, there are plenty of them.

Comment: Just replace it by the new version... or what do you mean? Put an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can store them as files on your HTTP server or generate them from database with any of server-side languages.